# Invalid column name error when passing Name parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

HI  I am trying to pass parameter first_name and when i pass in query and create parameter then this shows error

this is the query which used
[image: image1]

and this is the error i receive

[image: image2]

whereas when i use this query for  Customer_ID parameter this works but not works with Name.. where is the mistake? why not working with Name